# how to compare generic value and object

Tags: java

```
public boolean contains1(Object o) {
    System.out.println("ListIterator Approach: ");
    ListIterator < E > listIterator = list.listIterator();
    //System.out.println("true true true"+o);

    while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        // System.out.println(listIterator.next());

        System.out.println("\n" + "0: " + o + "  next" + listIterator.next() + "\n");

        if ((listIterator.next()).equals(o)) return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to overload contains method using iterator to compare the iterator next value and given object. but the result is always false. 
Please help resolve this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the `next()`  method   on `iterator` twice each time.

```
 System.out.println("\n"+"0: "+o+"  next"+listIterator.next()+"\n");  // once 

        if( (listIterator.next()).equals(o)) // twice 
           return true;
```

Hence the condition never satisfying.

If you want to use that Object multiple times inside, assign it to a reference and use that. Do not call `next()` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing `o` with the second next, because you called `listIterator.next()` twice.